# Linear regression weights and prediction in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am starting with Spark MLib library with Scala. As per my tests so far, I can not get the results even remotely correct. Was trying several ways to accomplish it with no success. As per now, even with relatively simple data:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10
```

I am unable to come to any decent results. Here is my code so far: [fairly standard I guess]

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val data = sc.textFile("/Users/jacek/oo.csv")
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(',')
    LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(Array(1.0, parts(1).toDouble)))
}

val numIterations = 20
val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterations)

val valuesAndPreds = parsedData.map { point =>
    val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
    (point.label, prediction)
}
```

Those are the results I am getting:

```
model: org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionModel = (weights=[-1.3423470408513295E21,-9.345181656001024E21], intercept=0.0)

scala> parsedData.take(10)
res48: Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] = Array((1.0,[1.0,1.0]), (2.0,[1.0,2.0]), (3.0,[1.0,3.0]), (4.0,[1.0,4.0]), (5.0,[1.0,5.0]), (6.0,[1.0,6.0]), (7.0,[1.0,7.0]), (8.0,[1.0,8.0]), (9.0,[1.0,9.0]), (10.0,[1.0,10.0]))

scala> valuesAndPreds.take(10)
res49: Array[(Double, Double)] = Array((1.0,-6.133210764535208E21), (2.0,-1.2266421529070415E22), (3.0,-1.8399632293605623E22), (4.0,-2.453284305814083E22), (5.0,-3.0666053822676038E22), (6.0,-3.6799264587211245E22), (7.0,-4.293247535174645E22), (8.0,-4.906568611628166E22), (9.0,-5.519889688081687E22), (10.0,-6.1332107645352076E22))

scala>
```

I've tried with different sets of LinearRegression algorithm settings without much luck. 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some tests here is the regression optimiser settings which would make the numbers as good as they can get, I suppose:

```
var regression = new LinearRegressionWithSGD().setIntercept(true)
regression.optimizer.setStepSize(0.1)
regression.optimizer.setNumIterations(1000)
val model2 = regression.run(parsedData)
```

Thanks @pzecevic for your help. You've pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't read your question thoroughly (sorry), but you probably need to set intercept to true:

```
val alg = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
alg.setIntercept(true)
alg.optimizer.setNumIterations(numIterations)
val model = alg.run(parsedData)
```

Besides, 20 iterations might be too little.